# Running multiple Terminal commands from Python File

Tags: python, linux, macos, terminal

So i have been messing about on my MacOS trying to run a Terminal command from within a Python File. Below is the code which i have been using so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess

print("IP Configuration for Machine")
cmd = ['ifconfig']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

o, e = proc.communicate()
print('OUTPUT: ' + o.decode('ascii'))
print('ERROR: '  + e.decode('ascii'))
print('CODE: ' + str(proc.returncode))
```

It works perfectly fine for when i intend to run only one Terminal Command. Right now i intend to run more than **one**, but so far it has been giving me errors. An example of my attempt:

```
print("IP Configuration for Machine & List Directory")
cmd = ['ifconfig', 'ls']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am wondering if there is a solution to my predicament

Comment: `Popen` takes the name of a command and its arguments, not two separate commands to be run sequentially. You need to use `subprocess.Popen` twice, once for each element of `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `Popen` is the name of *one* command to execute. To run reveral, run several subprocesses (or run one which runs many, i. e. a shell).

By the by, probably avoid bare `Popen` if you just need to run a process and wait for it to complete.

```py
for cmd in ['ifconfig', 'ls']:
    p = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True, text=True)
    print('output:', p.stdout)
    print('error:', p.stderr)
    print('result code:', p.returncode)
```

or

```
p = subprocess.run('ifconfig; ls', shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
print(p.stdout, p.stderr, p.returncode)
```

But usually [avoid a shell if you can, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)